# Splitting CSV data in Blender Game Engine with Python

Tags: python, csv, blender

I'm working on a small project in BGE and trying to import data.txt to a data.csv file and then split the data into 2 columns.

My data.txt looks like this;

```
Breathing rate:, 1.0
Pulse:, 140
Spinal Injury:, Yes
```

As you would guess, I want "," as a delimiter for the columns.

And here's my current code;

```
try:
    file = open(path+"dialogue.txt", 'r')
    info = file.readlines()
    own.text = str(info[currentLineNumber])
except:
    own.text = "end of script"

column1 = []
column2 = []
if own ["currentLine"] == 10:
    own.sendMessage("resume")
    with open(path+"data.txt", 'r') as in_file:
        stripped = (line.strip() for line in in_file)
        datalines = (line.split(",") for line in stripped if line)
        with open(path+"data.csv", 'w') as out_file:
            writer = csv.writer(out_file)
            writer.writerow(('subject', 'value'))
            writer.writerow(('ID: ', (uuid.uuid1())))
            writer.writerows(datalines)
os.rename(path+"data.csv", path+"newData.csv")
with open('newData.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        column1.append(row[0])
        column2.append(row[1])
```

I can import the data to data.csv but I can't split the data into columns, all the imported data in a single column. How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried just reading the file directly into CSV with a `csv.reader` object? It seems like the data is already in comma delimited format.  If you only want a subsection you could pump it into a StringIO and read that

Comment: I'm a newbie so I'm not sure if I understand you about reading the file directly with csv.reader object. I thought my "reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')" was the csv reader.

Comment: Your sample of data.txt is comma seperated, you are reading in  data.txt and manually splitting it on a comma and saving it as csv so you can read it in again. All you are doing is adding the ID line to the start of the file. I think what you are trying to do is take multiple lines from data.txt and put the second column of each line into columns in data.csv? That would be read 3 lines into var1, var2, var3 and then `writerow(ID,var1[1],var2[1],var3[1])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least if the format in your example is consistent, you can just do this:

```
datafile = "path/to/textfile"
with open (datafile, 'rt') as filehandle:
   csv_reader = csv.reader(filehandle, delimiter = ',')
   data = [row for row in csv_reader]
```

this will collect the comma-separated pairs into a list-of-lists like this:

```
[['Breathing rate:', ' 1.0'], ['Pulse:', ' 140'], ['Spinal Injury:', ' Yes']]
```

If the data you want is a subset of the larger file, you can copy it into a [stringIO](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) object and pass that to the csv reader instead; it will look like a disk file to the reader. Here's a simple example:

```
import StringIO
filtered_data = StringIO.StringIO()
with open(datafile, 'rt') as originalfile:
     for line in originalfile:
        if ":," in line:  # your real criteria would go here...
            filtered_data.write(line.strip() + "\n")

# rewind to beginning of your stringIO
filtered_data.seek(0) 
csv_reader = csv.reader(filtered_data, delimiter = ',')
data = [row for row in csv_reader]
```

I just guessed what the criteria for finding good lines actually -- you could use any logic you needed to pick only comma-separated lines

Comment: Funny thing happened; I followed your first suggestion (Blender doesn't have support for StringIO) and run the code again. The preview of the CSV file has changed; http://i.imgur.com/jXhhFVC.png but when I opened the file still all the data were in a single column; http://i.imgur.com/oVKxdvD.png

Comment: Oh well, looks like that was an Excel related well-known issue for viewing CSV files. Your suggestion worked perfectly, thank you.